# Unable to build a Dockerfile created by Visual Studio 2019 - Docker and Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, docker

After right clicking on my web api .NET Core 2.2 in Visual Studio 2019, and creating a `Dockerfile`, I found I am unable to manually do a `docker build` with a name and tag.  What I get is a huge image (about 1.8gb) with `<none>` and `<none>` as an ID and tag.

These are the steps:

After creating the file, I run Docker from VS and that then creates this image: `Snowdon...:dev` (260mb).  However, when I deploy this to Azure, the container terminates immediately.

If I run the image with another image using `docker-compose` this then creates a new image: `Snowdon...:latest` (269mb), then if I deploy this to Azure it works fine.

So, although I have this working in the cloud, I was wondering why I can't just do a `docker build`?

Here is the `Dockerfile` for my web api:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SnowdonAPI_05/SnowdonAPI_05.csproj", "SnowdonAPI_05/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SnowdonAPI_05/SnowdonAPI_05.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/SnowdonAPI_05"
RUN dotnet build "SnowdonAPI_05.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SnowdonAPI_05.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SnowdonAPI_05.dll"]
```

I am calling `build` from here:

[image: DIR]

Comment: from which folder are you calling `docker build`? I recall I had the same issue when I wasn't calling it from the root directory of the solution (if I remember correctly). so something along those lines `docker build -f myproject\path\Dockerfile .`

Comment: I'm in the root directory where the `Dockerfile` is, so my command is `docker build -t mynewimage .`

Comment: I understand that. And my suggestion was to try to call it from the root directory ;)

Comment: I've edited my question so you can see where I am calling it from.

Comment: well can you try my suggestion?

Comment: I'm sorry I getting errors as I can't see to get the command to work `docker build -f Repos\SnowdonAPI_05\SnowdonAPI_05\SnowdonAPI_05\Dockerfile .`  I am now in the `C` drive.  `error checking context: 'can't stat '\\?\C:\$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18''.`

Comment: I don't know your folder structure but try to run it from the folder where your `.sln` file is located

Comment: Ah yes, it works.... I think.  Its created an image `myimage` (268mb) which is the same size as the one that went to Azure.  However, its created a huge 1.78gb dangling image so I am guessing I can delete this.

Comment: Maybe that's the build image. If you look at the Dockerfile, it uses two different images: One for build (which includes the SDK) and one smaller one for serving. If you delete the build image, the next build might take longer again

Comment: Ah okay, thanks, well I have deleted it as you were probably writing your comment.  Weird how it creates an image with `dev` tag which is `8mb` smaller than the one that worked.  Now I have 2 images `268mb`, one that's on the cloud and one I have just created.  I'm assuming the new image will deploy to Azure fine like the other.  I suggest you create an answer, cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make this a solution for anybody else who comes across this:

If you manually want to run `docker build` on this, you need to execute this from the folder where your solution file (`.sln`) is located. So like this then:

```
docker build -f project\folder\Dockerfile -t mytag:1.0 .
```